# Understanding a UV Map/ How To Fix

Tags: modeling

[image][image]I've been having trouble understanding why a UV map comes out the way it does and i'm looking for some help on how to fix it and understanding why the issue occurs in the first place.The issue that i'm having is that the UV's for the model are unwrapping in a distorted way even though the model itself is symmetrical. Heres the file if it helps. https://ufile.io/wf2ts
Thanks

Comment: Please use the [edit] link at the bottom of your question and add an image that shows the UV map and illustrates the issue you are having. read [How to upload an image to a post?](https://meta.stackexchange.com/questions/75491/how-to-upload-an-image-to-a-post)

Comment: you don't have enough seams so that it can unwrap properly, you need to add some seams on the top face and on a edge of each corner